# Viewer for Markdown/MathJax rich text editing in vim/neovim?

Tags: neovim, filetype-markdown, large-documents, filetype-mathjax

## Problem Statement

Currently I use VIM in a terminal to write code. All my notes are on Microsoft Word 365, which I have been using for a long while.

I tried using markdown recently, used VIM to write the code, then preview the formatting in Google Chrome but faced a lot of problems.

Since my notes have lots of equations, I use MathJax to write the equations. If I use MathJax for inserting equations in Mardown documents, using VIM, there is no easy way to tell if the equation is correctly formatted. So, I have to preview the .md file in Google Chrome with a Google Chrome Extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog). However, when I load/reload/autoload the .md file in Google Chrome, it takes me to the top of the .md file, not at the last edited location, which tends to be far away from the current location.

## Question

Is there any Windows/Linux application which will show the formatted document (with images, equations etc) at the **current cursor location**, similar to when using Microsoft Word, when I am editing the .md file in VIM?

Comment: These are three very different questions.

Comment: Do you mean, I didnt correctly tie the questions to the problem statement? Or I should break it up into different posts?

Comment: Well, "preview mathjax", "syntax check mathjax/markdown', and "embed Vim in Atom" just seem entirely different questions to me. The first two are related only in that it involves mathjax. The third is completely different altogether. The answers to those three questions are very different. I recommend you ask only one question per question.

Comment: Oh ok.. thanks for the feedback.. I didnt want to create too many questions.. so combined them in one. I will break them out separately.

Comment: There's no problem with asking a bunch of questions, although it may not be a good idea to ask all 3 at the same time. Giving people a day or so to answer them may get better results.

Comment: It unclear exactly what kind of setup you want.. the title suggests WYSIWYG which has basically no relation to vim.  Side-by-side markup and output is fine but is definitely not called "WYSIWYG."

Comment: You are right.. I removed the WYSIWYG.. I removed the WYSIWYG word from the title.. The detailed question in under # Question.

Comment: I used Word as an example, because I am most familiar with rich text editing in Word. I know that VIM cant do WYSIWYG..  Let me know if the modifications above clarifies the questions better...